# Firefox и display:none

Tags: html, firefox, css

Подскажите, в чем беда: http://mir-m.com

Именно в огненной не срабатывает правило `display:none;`. Из за этого едет весь сайт.

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="fancyform" style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:auto;">
    <!-- Бокс вход -->
    <!--noindex-->
    <div id="boxLogin">
      <div class="boxcontent">
        <form id="loginbox" method="post" action="http://mir-m.com/login.php?action=process">
          форма
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/noindex-->
    <!-- /Бокс вход -->
  </div>
</div>
```

и внизу счетчики. Все теги закрыты.

---

**upd:** и вот в чем беда была

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/html" />` лиса не любит

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />`  все ок

Comment: И где там в этой груде кода искать ваш display? Но на будущее: [122 Errors, 27 warning(s)](hhttp://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmir-m.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Прежде чем спрашивать "что здесь не так", хорошо бы свести 
это соотношение к 0, 0.

Comment: ну как бы сколько бы этих "ошибок не было" они ж все из за того что скрипты в странице, что теэ начинается не на той строке. на style="display:none;" никак ж не должно влиять

Comment: Перепроверьте открытие/закрытие тегов. И укажите в вопросе, для какого именно элемента не срабатывает, по-вашему, правило `display:none`.

Comment: И внизу счетчики. Все теги закрыты.

`<div style="display: none;"><div id="fancyform" style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:auto;">
<!-- Бокс вход -->
<!--noindex-->
<div id="boxLogin">
<div class="boxcontent">
<form id="loginbox" method="post" action="http://mir-m.com/login.php?action=process">
форма
</form>
</div>
</div>
<!--/noindex-->
<!-- /Бокс вход --></div></div>`

Comment: Пробовали поотключать Redhelper и прочие динамические примочки временно?

Comment: да.вообще ни в какую.
стили в CSS отлично принимает.

Comment: Поскольку бага такого не замечено, и если сделать минимальный пример с тем же `display:none`, то всё работает — вывод, что где-то конфликтует что-то с чем-то, плюс вероятность косяков вёрстки. Я бы предложил отгрызать по куску кода от имеющегося, пока не заработает. Для начала отрубить все скрипты - возможно кто-то из них оверрайдит инлайн стиль этого дива.

Comment: попробовал отключить все скрипты и стили, а display:none все равно не сработало )))

при установке лисы что то за ошибка вылезала что мл хром эти же библиотеки использует.
у Вас то же в лисе видны счетчики и поля для входа не понятно где ?

Answer (score 2):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

Проблема была в `content`. Такое не работает в Firefox:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/html" />
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

А вот так - все нормально:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```